# How to get the value of a checkbox in data template of a combobox in datagrid in silverlight4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a combobox  inside a datagrid in silverlight4. I have placed a check box inside data template of combobox to make combobox multi-selectable. Now i want to get the values for selected items in combobox.So how i can do that ?

Here is my code :

```
 <ComboBox  Name="cbxitmes" Height="23" Width="255" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetItems,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=myname}"  SelectedValuePath="myvalue">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding myname}"  ></CheckBox>                            
                        </DataTemplate>                        
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

Please Help me guys.

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried to find the checkbox in combobox on dropdownclosed event but i am not getting checkbox values.
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(cbxitmes.ItemTemplate.LoadContent());

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, it might help http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/452756/Add-checkbox-inside-Combobox-in-Silverlight